# Calculate the integral $\oint_{C(0;2)}\frac{e^{2\pi z}-1}{z(z-i)}dz$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, contour-integration, complex-integration

Calculate the integral $$\oint_{C(0;2)}\frac{e^{2\pi z}-1}{z(z-i)}dz$$ where $C(0;2)$ is the circle with center $0$, radius $2$ and with positive direction of rotation.

$$$$

Do we have to write the function as a sum of two functions?

$$\frac{e^{2\pi z}-1}{z(z-i)}=\frac{A}{z} + \frac{B}{z-i}\Rightarrow e^{2\pi z}-1=A(z-1)+Bz=(A+B)z-A$$

But how can we continue from here?

Or is this approach wrong?

$$$$

**EDIT :**

We have that $$\frac{e^{2\pi z}-1}{z(z-i)}=\frac{\frac{e^{2\pi z}-1}{z}}{z-i}$$ There is a singularity at $z=i$.

Let $f(z)=\frac{e^{2\pi z}-1}{z}$.

Then we calculate $$\text{Res}_{z=i}2\pi i(f'(z))\mid_{z=i}$$

Is that correct so far?

Comment: You can just use the residue theorem if you know it, otherwise you could rework the contour so that you get two different contours where the function will have one pole interior to each, which is equivalent to the residue theorem

Comment: Partial fractions will not work like this since  $e^{2\pi z}$ depends on $z$.

Comment: Could you take a look at the edit part above? @StephenDonovan

Comment: @MaryStar Your answer is close, but you've added an additional prime on your function, it should just be $2\pi i (f(z))$ evaluated at i

Comment: Ah should it be $f(z)$ instead of $f'(z)$ ? @pleasantpheasant

Comment: @MaryStar That is correct.

Comment: Is the way I took the function $f(z)$ correct? Or should Ihave taken the whole function as $f(z)$ ? @pleasantpheasant

Comment: Actually, $z=i$ isn't a (non-removable) singularity, because$$\frac{e^{2\pi z}-1}{z(z-i)}=\frac{e^{2\pi(z-i)}-1}{z(z-i)}\sim\frac{2\pi}{z}\sim-2\pi i$$for $z\approx i$.

Comment: How did you get that? @J.G.

Comment: @MaryStar For small $w$, $\frac{e^{aw}-1}{w}\sim a$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do partial fraction decomposition here because of the term $e^{2\pi z}$. You only do that for [rational functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_function).

Let $\displaystyle f(z)=\frac{e^{2\pi z}-1}{z}$. Note that $z=0$ is a removable singularity of $f$. By the [Cauchy integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula),
$$
\oint_{C(0;2)}\frac{f(z)}{z-i}\;dz = 2\pi i f(i)=0
$$

Alternatively, you can consider the function $\displaystyle g(z)=\frac{e^{2\pi z}-1}{z(z-i)}$.

$\textrm{Rez}(g;0)=0$ since $0$ is a removable singularity of $g$.

$\textrm{Rez}(g;i)=\lim_{z\to i}(z-i)g(z)=0$.

By the Residue Theorem,
$$
\oint_{C(0;2)} g(z)\; dz=0
$$

Comment: Could you explain to me how exactly you applied Cauchy Theorem?

Comment: @MaryStar: basically you apply its corollary, the Cauchy integral formula.

Comment: Ah ok! So for example if we have $$\oint_{C(0;1)}\frac{\sin (\pi z)}{z(4z^2-1)}dz$$ then do we rewrite it as $$\frac{\sin (\pi z)}{z(4z^2-1)}=\frac{\sin (\pi z)}{z((2z)^2-1)}=\frac{\sin (\pi z)}{z(2z-1)(2z+1)}=\frac{\frac{\sin (\pi z)}{z(2z+1)}}{(2z-1)}=\frac{\frac{\sin (\pi z)}{2z(2z+1)}}{(z-\frac{1}{2})}$$ and so we take $f(z)=\frac{\sin (\pi z)}{2z(2z+1)}$. Have Iunderstood that correctly?

Comment: And so we get then $$\oint_{C(0;1)}\frac{f(z)}{z-\frac{1}{2}}\;dz = 2\pi i f\left (\frac{1}{2}\right )=\pi i$$ Is that correct? Or haven't I understood that properly?

Comment: But using the other way you showed we have Rez(g;0)=0, Rez(g;1/2)=1/2, Rez(g;-1/2)=-1/2 and by the formula we get 0, or  not? So at which way do I have done a mistake?

Comment: In your new example, the singularity $z=\frac12$ for $f$ is *not* removable; so you can't apply Cauchy theorem in that way.

Comment: So the second way is the correct ,  right?

Comment: @MaryStar: if your calculation of the residues is correct, then yes.

Comment: Ok, great!! I think I understood now your answer!! Thank you very much!! :-)

Comment: @MaryStar: you are welcome. Glad to help.